# How to select ::after when followed by a p

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Given this HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <hr />
</div>
```

I would like a nice dingbat in place of very last horizontal rule, and a blank line for the first one.

However, consider this HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Here, there should be a blank line for the `hr`, and no dingbat.

I was thinking I would put the dingbat in the content after each `hr`, then remove the content for any HR followed by a `p`:

```
hr {
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
hr::after {
  content: "❧"
}

hr::after + p {
  content: "";
}
```

That last rule, of course, doesn't work. :)

How do I set the `::after` content *only* when followed by a `p`? Or, is there a way to select only the last occurrence of the `hr` if it has no following element?

Comment: I would like some clarification; your first statement indicates you want the dingbat after the 2nd `p` (based on your HTML). Your second statement asks how to add a dingbat after *each* `p`. Your attempted code that you say doesn't work would place a dingbat only after the *1st* `p`. Which of these three scenarios are you looking to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was confusing. I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone will point out to you, correctly, that [there is no previous sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector), but you don't need one for this.

You can simply apply the dingbat to `hr` only when it's the last child like so:

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: medium solid;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
hr {
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
hr:last-child::after {
  content: "❧"
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <hr />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: OP's wording is a bit confusing to me, but `But I only want the dingbat to appear on the last hr in the div` sounds to me like the dingbat should be after the second `p`, not between the first and second.

Comment: @TylerH: Huh. You're right. Yeah that is very confusing, based on how hr works you would expect the last one to be hidden if there's no content following it. But I'm gonna err on the side of caution and edit to follow exactly what's been asked...

Comment: are pseudo element allowed on hr? will this work everywhere?

Comment: @Temani Afif: I remember reading something mentioning that most void elements can reliably have ::before and ::after pseudo-elements due to certain loopholes in how the DOM and CSS specs interact, but I don't remember what it was.

Comment: @Temani Afif: Not "most" void elements, but some, ones that are non-replaced elements.

Comment: I added a second example to further clarify. I *only* want the dingbat to appear on an `hr` that has no following sibling. With `:last-of-type`, the second HTML example still gets the dingbat.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify and only consider the `p` element without `hr`:

Not for the last

```css
p:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "❧";
  display:block;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Only for the last:

```css
p:last-child::after {
  content: "❧";
  display:block;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want it after every last `p`, I want it on the last `hr` if it's not followed by a `p`.